# mongodb $cond if array is not empty

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to add a push with a conditional "if myArray.length > 0" basically:

```
$push: {
    $cond: [
            { // how check if myArray.length > 0 here? },
            1, // this value is just for testing
            "$$REMOVE"
    ]
}
```

So far none of the combinations I have tried or online answers have worked, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you looking for ```{$gt: [{$size: "$myArray"}, 0]}```?

Comment: I tried that but get 'the argument to $size must be an array, but was of type missing', I read online this could happen if there is a null array, so how can I add a null check here? I tried ```{ "$gt": [ {$size: { "$ifNull": [ "$ticketList", [] ] }}, 1]},``` but I guess that's not quite it.

Comment: Make a normal `{$push: "$myArray"}` and update that fields afterwards in an additional stage.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't check the length of `myArray` if it is missing or otherwise not an array, you need a nested `$cond`.

The outer one tests if the type of `myarray` to make sure it is an array, the inner one checks the length of the array.

```
        $cond: {
          if: {$eq: [ "array", {$type: "$myArray" }]},
          then: {
           $cond: {
              if: {$gt: [{ $size: "$MYARRAY"}, 0]},
              then: 1,
              else: "$$REMOVE"
           }},
          else: "$$REMOVE"
        }
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3oZFSEEjVne)